# Printing a PHP 2D Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>Distance</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php

        $distance = array(
            array(0, 200, 57, 223),
            array(200, 0, 150, 5),
            array(57, 150, 0, 177),
            array(57, 150, 0, 177),
            array(223, 5, 177, 0)
        );

        $cityA = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cityA");
        $cityB = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "cityB");
        $result = $distance[$cityA][$cityB];

        print "<p> The distance between the 2 cities is $result</p>";

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

For the code:

```
 print "<p> The distance between the 2 cities is $result</p>";
```

The result is:

```
The distance between the 2 cities is 177
```

But if I change it to:

```
 print "<p> The distance between the 2 cities is $distance[$cityA][$cityB]</p>";
```

The result becomes:

```
The distance between the 2 cities is Array[0]
```

Could anyone explain why $distance[$cityA][$cityB] is not interpreted as an 2D array when I try to print it directly?

Comment: What are the values of `$cityA` and `$cityB`?

Comment: You need to change your `$distance` array to have both keys and values, because I don't see how your script knows which city has what coordinates.

Comment: @David: It *does* have keys, that how arrays work.  They are numeric.  From 0-4, and 0-3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to wrap it in curly braces.

```
print "<p> The distance between the 2 cities is {$distance[$cityA][$cityB]}</p>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, Rocket. But why is my approach not working? PHP should understand $var and should recognize it when I put it in a print statement.

Comment: @fall: It seems PHP stops parsing at the 1st `]`, and the 2nd `[$cityB]` isn't read as part of the variable.